# How to sort a array value using PHP mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

My DB Table field Contain value with array of data I need to sort the first value alone

```
Pid | Price
  1 | 213,4566,112
  2 | 100,452,567
  3 | 653,344,6322
  4 | 55,222,42,44
  5 | 522
```

I want it to be sorted with price first value in ascending order like below

```
Pid | Price    
  4 | 55,222,42,44
  2 | 100,452,567
  1 | 213,4566,112
  5 | 522
  3 | 653,344,6322
```

I need a Mysql query using PHP.

Comment: You shouldn't store comma separated data into a field like that.  You should use a separate table to store the prices, one row per price (so if you looked up the pid in that table you'd get multiple rows back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Price, ',', 1) AS SIGNED) ASC
```

**Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f7b7/2

> **Hint:** You should avoid a column like `Price` with comma seperated values.
>   Normalize your database / tables!

Comment: I think you may actually want to use `CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Price, ',', 1) AS SIGNED)` so they are sorted as numbers, not strings.  Otherwise `100` (Pid 2) may be first.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - that's right! updated and added demo